# check if tuple is null or not

Tags: c#, tuples

how do I check whether a variable of a tuple datatype is null or not in C#?

```
                 var allUsers = new List<PersonEntity>();
                 var response = await context.CallActivityAsync<(List<PersonEntity> entities, TableContinuationToken continuationToken)>(
                                                                nameof(ChildEntitiesFilterFunction),
                                                                new ChildEntitiesFilterRequest
                                                                {
                                                                    ContinuationToken = null,
                                                                    Query = filter,
                                                                    SyncJob = request.SyncJob,
                                                                    SourceTableName = directReportCloudTableName,
                                                                });
                allUsers.AddRange(response.entities);
```

adding an if condition if (response == null) didn't work

[image]

adding if conditions if (response.entities == null) if (response.ContinuationToken) are giving nullreference exception error.

Comment: please avoid posting questions multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Value tuples are value types and by default cannot be null. If you are getting null reference exceptions, then something else is going on.

You could also consider destructuring the tuple to make it easier to work without:

```
var (entities, continuationToken) = await context.CallActivityAsync<(List<PersonEntity>, TableContinuationToken)>
```